# How to load an OBJ/MTL file in THREE.js from a browser upload?

Tags: three.js

I've implemented many 3D viewers in THREE where the assets are hosted somewhere, but I'm running into a unique situation where we'd like to preview a model before it gets stored on the server.

How would you go about uploading an OBJ with MTL textures and be able to render it by having these formats reference once another, just as they would if you were retrieving them as a served resource?

Comment: Can you clarify this question? I'm not sure what storing stuff on the server has to do with client side canvas / webgl rendering.

Comment: So, if you look at all examples on the THREE.js site, you'll find that the assets are all being served up (i.e. they are hosted on some server). I need to load a model from a user upload immediately, rather than needing to store it on a server to be AJAX before a preview

Comment: Is this related to either webgl or threejs? Three.js doesn't care if stuff is on the server, or generated in the client. How are you "uploading", do you have some code? Why are you even considering sending it to the server... only to send it back?

Comment: Do you mean [how to read local files](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)? You would probably then want to send the file contents to the OBJLoader and MTLLoader parse functions, etc. Does the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) load local files, I'm not sure, take a look at it.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but with MTL and OBJ files, they reference one another within their contents. So, I'm wondering how one would go about achieving this without hosting the statics somewhere...

Comment: It's like 2pha says, let the user load a file using the method from the link. 
OBJ and MTL files are just text files. With the loaded data, use MTLLoader.parse() instead of MTLLoader.load() ( and also OBJLoader.parse() ).
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=obj#webgl_loader_obj_mtl. There are a lot of examples and documentation on THREE.js there.